# How to connect two tus severs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cloudflare, tus

I want to upload a file with resume capability to Cloudflare (tus enabled API). I cannot upload a file directly from the browser to Cloudflare because the credentials should not be visible. So, I have to use tus-node-server as an express middleware on the back-end.

I do not want to upload the file completely on my own server and after that start uploading the file to Cloudflare.  Is there a way to pipe the tus-node-server middleware to Cloudflare upload API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I received this answer from project's Github](https://github.com/tus/tus-node-server/issues/182#issuecomment-840563990)